# mod_passenger "Cannot connect to Unix socket" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, passenger

I'm trying to access a couple of Rails apps (Redmine, toto) running in Apache by way of mod_passenger and get the following error in my Apache error logs:

```
[ pid=11154 thr=3076008592 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:884 time=2012-07-25 17:25:02.921 ]: Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot connect to Unix socket '/tmp/passenger.1.0.10257/generation-0/socket': Permission denied (13)
  Backtrace:
 in 'Passenger::ApplicationPool::Client* Passenger::ApplicationPool::Client::connect(const std::string&, const std::string&, const Passenger::StaticString&)' (Client.h:438)
 in 'Passenger::ApplicationPool::Client* Hooks::getApplicationPool()' (Hooks.cpp:286)
 in 'Passenger::SessionPtr Hooks::getSession(const Passenger::PoolOptions&)' (Hooks.cpp:312)
 in 'int Hooks::handleRequest(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:585)
```

Here are my Apache Passenger conf files:

```
$ cat passenger.conf
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14
  PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
  PassengerDefaultUser www-data
</IfModule>
$ cat passenger.load
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04, Apache 2.2.17, Ruby 1.9.1, Rails 3.2.6, Passenger 3.0.14.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: My /tmp directory somehow acquired permissions 700, hence the permission denied. I don't remember doing that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you need to sort out is this:

```
'/tmp/passenger.1.0.10257/generation-0/socket': Permission denied (13)
```

However tmp usually has the sticky bit set which limits what non-owners can do with files (and a big reason for using a unix socket is for privilege seperation). Really a socket shouldn't be in /tmp at all. Somewhere in /var is a more sensible location.

Yes, your permissions on /tmp are wrong and you're going to get other weird stuff happenning as a result.